# Example of a histogram using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, histogram

Does anyone have sample wxWidgets code to display a histogram?  wxMathPlot seems to be working great for my other plotting needs, but now I have a requirement for a histogram.

Not being a UI developer I am a little bit like a fish out of water.

Any suggestions or references are greatly appreciated.

(I'd like it to be a dynamic histogram layer on a frame - meaning I will be adding values over time and I want the plot to update.

[I did find this](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2009/08/13/simple-histogram-widget-for-wxwidgets/), but I'd rather just make/use a histogram class than do the low level drawing.

Answer (score 2):

I did not use the following by my own, so I am not aware about the quality.
The bar chart of [wxFreeChart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/freechart/) or [wxChart](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/wxchart/), found [here](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/complist.php?compperpage=1000&viewmode=full&browseby=category&section=graphics&page=1), seem to me good candidates.
For the dynamic update you have to take care, that the model element informs the view element about changes (e.g. via callback) in the data, so the view knows that it has to re-draw the chart.
I hope this helps.